# Is there a way to fetch MySQL records using different ID alias's

Tags: php, html, mysql, wamp

I am trying to fetch records using different aliases but they are however related.

The server I'm using is WAMP. I have successfully connected my project/script to the PhpMyAdmin database and some records can be seen on my PHP file using some queries and be successfully inserted.

However, when I try to fetch records using different aliases I get an error stating the following: **"MySQL said: #1066 - Not Unique table/alias:'teams'"**?

Can you please explain whats going on because on the database when I check the ID's of these records, they show that they are connected/pulling the record from another table.

The following is my MySQL query in which I tried to alter several times but no success came about after every attempt:

```
SELECT DISTINCT fixtures.fixture_id, fixtures.fixture_date,
        fixtures.fixture_time, fixtures.home_teamID, 
        fixtures.away_teamID, fixtures.comp_id 
From fixtures 
    JOIN teams ON fixtures.home_teamID = teams.team_id 
    JOIN teams ON fixtures.away_teamID = teams.team_id 
    JOIN competitions ON fixtures.comp_id = competitions.comp_id 
ORDER BY fixture.id ASC
```

The Error Message from the query states that:

```
SELECT DISTINCT fixtures.fixture_id, fixtures.fixture_date, 
        fixtures.fixture_time, fixtures.home_teamID, 
        fixtures.away_teamID, fixtures.comp_id 
From fixtures 
    JOIN teams ON fixtures.home_teamID = teams.team_id 
    JOIN teams ON fixtures.away_teamID = teams.team_id 
    JOIN competitions ON fixtures.comp_id = competitions.comp_id 
ORDER BY fixture.id ASC 
LIMIT 0, 25
```

Please explain to me what am I doing wrong and please note I am new to this platform using PHP and MySQL. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are joining to `teams` twice, but I don't see any reason for doing this.  Is there a reason for doing this?

Comment: You need to give the team table an alias the second time you join to it.

Comment: @TIM - The reason is that both "away_teamID and home_teamID" tables fetch their records from this TEAM table

Comment: @KIKO - can you show me a sample on how to do as I said I am new to this environment; thank in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want join two ime the same table you need  alias

```
  SELECT DISTINCT fixtures.fixture_id
        , fixtures.fixture_date
        , fixtures.fixture_time
        , fixtures.home_teamID
        , fixtures.away_teamID
        , fixtures.comp_id 
        , a.team_name home_team
        , b.team_name  away_team
  From fixtures 
      JOIN teams  a ON fixtures.home_teamID = a.team_id 
      JOIN teams  b ON fixtures.away_teamID = b.team_id 
      JOIN competitions ON fixtures.comp_id = competitions.comp_id 
  ORDER BY fixture.id ASC
```

in this sample a and b are the alias for the same table used  in two way one for home_team and one for way_team

and for a more compact code  as  suggested  by  @Tim Biegeleisen you can use alias as

```
  SELECT DISTINCT f.fixture_id
        , f.fixture_date
        , f.fixture_time
        , f.home_teamID
        , f.away_teamID
        , f.comp_id 
        , a.team_name home_team
        , b.team_name  away_team
  From fixtures f 
      JOIN teams  a ON f.home_teamID = a.team_id 
      JOIN teams  b ON f.away_teamID = b.team_id 
      JOIN competitions c  ON f.comp_id = c.comp_id 
  ORDER BY f.id ASC
```

Comment: is there a way I can show the names instead of the IDs, thanks for the helpful answer :D

Comment: the TEAMS table has the following fields: team_id, team_name, team_email. Now, I want home_teamID and away_teamID; which are from FIXTURES table, to show the names instead of the IDs of the TEAMS table. Is there a way around this?

Comment: the code  i provided  should return  what you  asked in comment  above..  what's the problem???

Comment: thanks the error has been resolved. I am getting names instead of the query displaying IDs...

Answer (score 0):

You're joining 'teams' two times, so when you refer to 'teams' it doesn't know whether you mean the first teams that was joined on home_teamID or the second one that was joined on away_teamID.

You fix this by giving each join a different name like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT fixtures.fixture_id, fixtures.fixture_date,
        fixtures.fixture_time, fixtures.home_teamID, 
        fixtures.away_teamID, fixtures.comp_id 
From fixtures 
    JOIN teams AS hometeams ON fixtures.home_teamID = hometeams.team_id 
    JOIN teams AS awayteams ON fixtures.away_teamID = awayteams.team_id 
    JOIN competitions ON fixtures.comp_id = competitions.comp_id 
ORDER BY fixture.id ASC
```

Comment: Why not consistently use aliases everywhere?

Comment: @MiK - thanks for the snippet. I will test it and get back to you with regards to the outcome of this sample....

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen unless you have a clear policy on aliases in your dev team, it might add further confusion when one guy always gives teams the alias "footballers" and the next dev does a query where he gives teams the alias "soccerplayers". i.e. it makes it harder to "know" your database by always making you look up what the alias means. It's only an additional glance but it can add up. On the other hand you need aliases in cases such as these, and they also make sense (with a short alias like "a") when you need to refer to the same table many times in a query.

Comment: @MiK Fair enough, but the consensus of the broader SQL community is to use aliases, and also to be consistent when writing SQL code.

Comment: @MiK - is there a way I can show the record name instead of the ID because now the query works perfectly, however, it returns the ID instead of the NAME for each ID field?

Comment: I don't know the specifics of your DB, but instead of SELECTing *fixtures.home_teamID* and *fixtures.away_teamID*, you need to select *hometeams.teamname* and *awayteams.teamname*

Comment: @Mik - FIXTURES table has: fixture_id, fixture_time, fixture_date, home_teamID, away_teamID, comp_id. The TEAMS table has: team_id, team_name, team_email. The COMPETITIONS table has: comp_id and comp_name. These are my DB specs

Comment: Then you need to select hometeams.team_name and awayteams.team_name instead of fixtures.home_teamID and fixtures.away_teamID in the SELECT section

Comment: Thanks this also help me understand the fundamentals of using ALIASES. Thanks a lot